# how to detect android device plug in os in c#

Tags: c#, android

I want create an win application with `c#` to automatically detect android device such as mobile phone, and detect any file/files send or receive to android device are detect and captured.
But i can only detect USB devices such as `flash memory` with `c#`.

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
.Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);
```

Can you help me??